# what does Pn options stands for in nmap

Tags: nmap, scan

I have a very weak memory, and i can't remember an option unless i understand what it stands for.

I can remember -sT option in nmap because i know that s stands for scan, and T for TCP Connect.

I know that -Pn skips the ping discovery and assumes directly that the host is up, but what does the P and the n stands for in -Pn ?

Comment: nmap man pages and the help text for the command itself will tell you all this. Knowing where to find the answer is better than memorizing the answer.

Comment: @schroeder the user asked about the mnemonic of nmap switches. Man page remain just man..ual page and it doesn't cover that kind of content.

Comment: @elsadek I know. One doesn't need a mnemonic when one has the documentation.

Comment: @schroeder i know that i have documentation, but i need to remember the option in my head, not going through pages of manual to remember it each time i wanna scan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a cheat sheet that summarizes all nmap switches.
https://pentestlab.wordpress.com/2012/08/17/nmap-cheat-sheet/ 
Notice all ping-related switches begin with **'P'**, so I assume **Pn** means **Ping Not**. 
 
I thing it easy to remember now :)

Comment: Yes, this is the intention. In 2010, the old `-PN` and `-P0` names were replaced with `-Pn`, and `-sP` was replaced by `-sn`. This is so that the mnemonic for `n` means "don't do this." So `-n` means "don't do name resolution," `-Pn` means "don't do host discovery," and `-sn` means "don't do a port scan."